# How to prevent race conditions in a distributed nodejs web servers architecture backed by mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, distributed

Here' s the description of my problem:

1. I have x web workers written in nodejs (express.js) behind a load ballancer. These workers write data into mongodb (mongoose.js)
2. I've setup endpoint y such that at some point in the middleware chain of the handler I'm doing the following logic: If the requesting user exists in the database, then fetch it, update some fields then store it back. If it doesn't exist, insert it in mongo.

NOTE! I'm unable to use Mongoose's findAndUpdateOne() - which would be atomic - due to domain specific logic, ie. if the user already exists update it with a certain value, else insert it with another value.

1. The problem is, quite often, two requests from the same user (who doesn't yet exist in the db) will hit two different workers. When user processing middleware kicks in, both workers will determine that the user doesn't exist and attempt to insert it then update it. Naturally this causes errors, eg. validation errors: I've setup a unique email per user validation and others.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: why can't you just do an upsert? You can do an upsert that looks for a user and performs the field update. If the user doesn't exist, then an insert is done. This is atomic and is faster than findAndModify

Comment: @DylanTong because in case the user already exists in the db i want to set slightly different data from the case when I just insert it, specifically a `createdAt` field should be set to `Date.now` when the user is new, but preserved to the original value if the user is updated

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact use case is, but it is still possible to do an upsert eg) db.users.update({_id:{userid:1,createdAt:now}},{$set:{stuff:"new value2"}},{upsert:true}). This is one possibility of many. Some testing would have to do be done to determine which one has the best balance of simplicity and speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$set` and `$setOnInsert` update operators to achieve that.

From [MongoDB $setOnInsert docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert):

> If an update operation with upsert: true results in an insert of a
>   document, then $setOnInsert assigns the specified values to the fields
>   in the document. If the update operation does not result in an insert,
>   $setOnInsert does nothing.

and

> If the db.collection.update() with upsert: true had found a matching document, then MongoDB performs an update, applying the $set operation but ignoring the $setOnInsert operation.

so, this should do the trick:

```
var now = Date.now();

Users.update({ _id: 1 }, {
  $set:         { updatedAt: now },
  $setOnInsert: { createdAt: now }
}, {upsert: true}, function(err, doc) {

  // resultant doc is available here

})
```

Comment: This is brilliant! I didn't know you could do this!